# How do I draw the selected list-box item in a different color?

Tags: delphi, listbox, ownerdrawn

Is is possible to change the item selection focus color and text color in a TListBox?

When themes are not enabled in the project, or the list box style is set to owner-draw, the selection around the item is painted blue, which I believe is globally defined by the system's appearance settings.

I would like to change the color of selected items to a custom color.

So an example, the result would be something like this:

[image]

Note the last listbox has been modified in Paint to illustrate the example.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  with (Control as TListBox).Canvas do
  begin
    if odSelected in State then
      Brush.Color := $00FFD2A6;

    FillRect(Rect);
    TextOut(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, (Control as TListBox).Items[Index]);
    if odFocused In State then begin
      Brush.Color := ListBox1.Color;
      DrawFocusRect(Rect);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @Craig - Make sure users do not have similar window text color.

Comment: Thanks @Sertac I will consider that.

Comment: Tried this but the TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem procedure is never called, i put a breakpoint on it and it never stops on this. What am i missing ?

Comment: Doesn't that require ListBox1.Style to be one of the lbOwnerDrawXxxx values?

Answer (score 2):

I saw, Style property has to be lbOwnerDrawFixed

Answer (score 0):

This helped me do something I needed to do also, namely, eliminate any visible selection.  I modified the code above very slightly to accomplish this:

```
procedure TForm1.OnDrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  with (Control as TListBox).Canvas do
  begin
    if odSelected in State then
    begin
      Brush.Color := clWhite;
      Font.Color := clBlack;
    end;

    FillRect(Rect);
    TextOut(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, (Control as TListBox).Items[Index]);
    if odFocused In State then begin
      Brush.Color := ListBox1.Color;
      DrawFocusRect(Rect);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Made the selected item's background color white, and it's font color black, which did what I needed. Thanks so much!