# Changing font or color of an specific Checklistbox Item?

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi XE-3.
I wish to change to color or font of a single item in an checklistbox.
Is this possible?

Comment: or simulating checklistbox wit h3rd-party controls like VTW

Comment: Similar/duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563508/how-do-i-draw-the-selected-list-box-item-in-a-different-color

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to use owner drawing on for your check list box. Set the [`Style`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomListBox.Style) property of your check list box to `lbOwnerDrawFixed` and write the handler for the [`OnDrawItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomListBox.OnDrawItem) event. In this event handler you can use something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.CheckListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
var
  Flags: Longint;
begin
  with (Control as TCheckListBox) do
  begin
    // modifying the Canvas.Brush.Color here will adjust the item color
    case Index of
      0: Canvas.Brush.Color := $00F9F9F9;
      1: Canvas.Brush.Color := $00EFEFEF;
      2: Canvas.Brush.Color := $00E5E5E5;
    end;
    Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    // modifying the Canvas.Font.Color here will adjust the item font color
    case Index of
      0: Canvas.Font.Color := clRed;
      1: Canvas.Font.Color := clGreen;
      2: Canvas.Font.Color := clBlue;
    end;
    Flags := DrawTextBiDiModeFlags(DT_SINGLELINE or DT_VCENTER or DT_NOPREFIX);
    if not UseRightToLeftAlignment then
      Inc(Rect.Left, 2)
    else
      Dec(Rect.Right, 2);
    DrawText(Canvas.Handle, Items[Index], Length(Items[Index]), Rect, Flags);
  end;
end;
```

Here's the result of the above example:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't cover state of the item (if it's focused, selected or not) and ignores VCL styles.