# Delphi change item background in listbox when double clicked

Tags: delphi, listbox, delphi-xe2

I would like to be able to change item's background to red when they are double clikced and make them stay that color so I can do something with only the red ones on FormClose for instance.(ex: OnClose delete only the red items) Is that possible with standard component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to owner-draw the ListBox.  Set its `Style` property to either `lbOwnerDraw`, `lbOwnerDrawVariable`, or `lbVirtualOwnerDraw`, and then use its `OnDrawItem` event to draw the items however you want (in the case of `lbOwnerDrawVariable`, you will also have to provide an `OnMeasureItem` event handler).  You will have to keep track of which items have been double-clicked, and then you can draw those items differently than the other items.  For example:

```
type
  MyItem = record
    Text: String;
    DblClicked: Boolean;
  end;

MyItems: array of MyItem;
```

```
var
  Item: MyItem;
begin
  SetLength(MyItems, ...);

  MyItems[0].Text := 'Item Text';
  MyItems[0].DblClicked := False;

  ...

  for Item in MyItems do
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Item.Text);
end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Pos: DWORD;
  Pt: TPoint;
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Pos := GetMessagePos;
  Pt.X := Smallint(LOWORD(Pos));
  Pt.Y := Smallint(HIWORD(Pos));
  Index := ListBox1.ItemAtPos(ListBox1.ScreenToClient(Pt), True);
  if Index <> -1 then
  begin
    MyItems[Index].DblClicked := True;
    ListBox1.Invalidate;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  if MyItems[Index].DblClicked then
  begin
    ListBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
    ListBox1.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
  end else
  begin
    ListBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := ListBox1.Color;
    ListBox1.Canvas.Font.Color := ListBox1.Font.Color;
  end;
  ListBox1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  ListBox1.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, Rect.Left + 2, Rect.Top + 2, MyItems[Index].Text);
end;
```

Comment: But I need it to be OnDblClick event. Could you provide an example please?

Comment: The `OnDblClick` event cannot change the colors directly, however it can be used to keep track of which items have been double-clicked, and it can`Invalidate()` the ListBox to trigger redraws, and then the `OnDrawItem` even can draw the currently tracked double-clicked items using different colors as needed.

Comment: What would you suggest to keep track of them?

Comment: Setting `MultiSelect` property allows to use the `Selected[ix]` property. Select by shift click. You can define a `OnDblClick` event to emulate a selection.

Comment: @LURD That's interesting. How would I change the background color then?

Comment: Like this, [`How do I draw the selected list-box item in a different color?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563508/how-do-i-draw-the-selected-list-box-item-in-a-different-color).

Comment: Great. I'm trying to emulate the selection by using ListBox.Selected[ListBox.ItemIndex]:=TRUE but it's not working though

Comment: Seems as a single click selects/deselects. Maybe this is enough.