# Select DBListbox Item in different color and Insert text

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

I am able to change the color of the items in DBCombobox using its Style as csOwnerDrawFixed similar to
[How do I draw the selected list-box item in a different color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563508/how-do-i-draw-the-selected-list-box-item-in-a-different-color?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
procedure TForm1.DBComboBoxDrawItem(Control:TWinControl;
   Index: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
with (Control as TDBComboBox).Canvas do
begin
 if odSelected in State then
  Brush.Color := $00EACAB6;
  Font.Color := clBlack;
  FillRect(Rect);
  TextOut(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, (Control as TDBComboBox).Items[Index]);
  if odFocused In State then
  begin
    Brush.Color := (Control as TDBComboBox).Color;
    DrawFocusRect(Rect);
   end; {if}
  end; {with} 
end;
```

Generally, By default i am able to use the DBCombobox Standard (style :csDropdown) to choose the items and also to enter the text in DB Combobox

But the problem i am facing currently is, when i change the color of DBCombobox using (Style as csOwnerDrawFixed or csOwnerDrawVariable). The color gets changed but i am not able enter the text in DBCombobox.

Could someone tell me how can i change the color of items and could enter the text in the DBCombobox at the same time. Thanks !

[image]

Note: The Color Shown is not the default one but the modified one

Comment: Can you show us what you have so we can reproduce?

Comment: Sorry, I meant code-wise. I should have made that clear.

Comment: For a DBComboBox the help explicitly states that this is not possible (I.e. in these modes users cannot input data). As a suggestion you might consider using a normal TCombobox and link it to the data source via live bindings, but I appreciate that this could be a major shift.

Answer (score 0):

With `TComboBox` it is possible. Try this. You can add `CloseUp` and `DropDown` event handlers

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TComboBox(Sender).Style := csDropDown
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TComboBox(Sender).Style := csOwnerDrawFixed;
end;
```

For `TDBComboBox` there is no `OnCloseUp` event so you can handle another event for instance `OnChange`:

```
procedure TForm1.DBComboBox1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
   TDBComboBox(Sender).Style := csDropDown
end;

procedure TForm1.DBComboBox1DropDown(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TDBComboBox(Sender).Style := csOwnerDrawFixed;
end;
```

or set the Style in the `Application.OnIdle` event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Idle(Sender: TObject; var Done: Boolean);
begin
  if (not DBComboBox1.DroppedDown) and (DBComboBox1.Focused)
  then
    DBComboBox1.Style := csDropDown;
  if (not DBComboBox1.DroppedDown) and (not DBComboBox1.Focused)
  then
    DBComboBox1.Style := csOwnerDrawFixed;
end;
```

Comment: I also thought of this, but when I tried it, it did not seem to work. The OnDrawItem event was not triggered.

Comment: @Dsm It will be triggered when `DBComboBox`.`Style` is set to `csOwnerDraw*`

Comment: It wasn't for me. I put a break point in the routine and it was not triggered. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: @Thanks for the solution. I have tried your first approach with DBCombobox using Change and Dropdown event handlers. But However it works only one instance. When i make dropdown second time it throws an error

Comment: @Dsm Your issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563508/how-do-i-draw-the-selected-list-box-item-in-a-different-color?noredirect=1&lq=1). Read the answers and comments in that q. My answer works fine for me.