# Changing color for specific items in a listbox

Tags: delphi, listbox, vcl

I am creating a messaging application and I want to have chats in a listbox (the selection of chats) and I want to change a name to green when someone is online. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need to set the ListBox.Style to lbOwnerDrawFixed and implement OnDrawItem event where you then get full control on how you want to have the listbox item displayed.

Comment: Have a look at [How do I draw the selected list-box item in a different color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563508/how-do-i-draw-the-selected-list-box-item-in-a-different-color/8563993)

Answer (score 2):

This is easy. You only need to owner draw the list box.

Set the list box's `Style` to `lbVirtualOwnerDraw` and assign its `OnData` and `OnDrawItem` handlers:

```pascal
unit ChatMainForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,
  Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls, Generics.Collections;

type
  TUserData = record
    UserName: string;
    Online: Boolean;
  end;

  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    lbUsers: TListBox;
    procedure lbUsersData(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
      var Data: string);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure lbUsersDrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect: TRect;
      State: TOwnerDrawState);
  private
    FUserData: TList<TUserData>;
  public

  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

uses
  Math;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  function usr(const AUserName: string; AOnline: Boolean): TUserData;
  begin
    Result.UserName := AUserName;
    Result.Online := AOnline;
  end;

begin

  FUserData := TList<TUserData>.Create;
  FUserData.Add(usr('Andreas Rejbrand', True));
  FUserData.Add(usr('John Doe', False));
  FUserData.Add(usr('Mary Smith', True));
  FUserData.Add(usr('Bill Evans', False));
  FUserData.Add(usr('Jonathan Stone', True));
  FUserData.Add(usr('Gary Jones', True));

  lbUsers.Count := FUserData.Count;

end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FUserData.Free;
end;

procedure TMainForm.lbUsersData(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  var Data: string);
begin
  if InRange(Index, 0, FUserData.Count - 1) then
    Data := FUserData[Index].UserName;
end;

procedure TMainForm.lbUsersDrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
const
  BackColors: array[Boolean] of TColor = (clWindow, clWindow);
  TextColors: array[Boolean] of TColor = (clGrayText, clWindowText);
begin
  if InRange(Index, 0, FUserData.Count - 1) then
  begin
    lbUsers.Canvas.Brush.Color := BackColors[FUserData[Index].Online];
    lbUsers.Canvas.Font.Color := TextColors[FUserData[Index].Online];
    if odSelected in State then
    begin
      lbUsers.Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;
      lbUsers.Canvas.Font.Color := clHighlightText;
    end;
    lbUsers.Canvas.Font.Style := [];
    if FUserData[Index].Online then
      lbUsers.Canvas.Font.Style := [fsBold];
    lbUsers.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
    InflateRect(Rect, -2, -2);
    var S := FUserData[Index].UserName;
    lbUsers.Canvas.TextRect(Rect, S,
      [tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter, tfEndEllipsis]);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot of result]

Clearly you need to tweak the code a bit to make it look good, but at least this should give you a nice start.

Comment: First exercise: instead of always having white background change the "online" ones to `clLime`. 